# can someone look at this blend file for a sec and tell me why its rendering black?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, import, image

gone through all the regular bases here. im puzzled

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PMwJVFTOEmRfRU6SaOAV0tDjj_6qIsI_/view?usp=sharing

thanks guys

Comment: Hi Harry. Welcome to Stack Exchange. First you should upload a version of your blend file which does what you say. Which you didn't. i rendered yours and i got: [![enter image description here][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LVEJ.jpg. Second you should write more about what you really tried, and not "all regular bases". And maybe it would be a good beginning to write that you are a total beginner (if you are and i think you are) so we know what we can presuppose and don't give answer you won't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  In your collection Cabinets you have an object Cabinets that is a huge mess:

[image: object cabinets]

[image: what it looks like]

remove that object and the scene renders fine.